# Prove that there exists a $w$ between $u$ and $v$ such that $f(w)(b-a)=\int_a^b f(t) dt$

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Intro to Topology by Mendelson.

The problem statement is,

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous. Let $U=f(u)$ and $V=f(v)$ such that $U\leq f(x)\leq V$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Prove that there is a $w\in[u,v]$ such that $f(w)(b-a)=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$.

I was able to prove that using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, Mean Value Theorem, and the Intermediate Value Theorem. Yet, I feel as though I really shouldn't use them (except for the IVT), since the first two have not been covered in the text.

The proof I did was,

Define the function $F(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ by $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt.$$ Then by the first part of the FTC we have that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$, that is, $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$. Since $F$ satisfies the conditions for the MVT, there exists a $w\in(a,b)$ such that $$F'(w)=\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}.$$ Now we have, $$\int_b^b f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)=f(w)(b-a).$$

I don't think I completely proved the statement, since I didn't show that $w\in[u,v]$.
The part of the book this problem is taken from is where they introduced the IVT and the Fixed-Point Theorem. I've been thinking of how I might use the maximum and minimum given, but nothing has been promising.

Thank you for any hints or feedback on how to approach this proof differently.

Comment: You used the mean value theorem? The statement you were trying to prove IS the mean value theorem!

Comment: Now that I take a better look at it, you're right. But, you would need to use the fundamental theorem of calculus on $f$ to get the mean value theorem right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the Mean Value Theorem, using the fact that $U \leq f(x) \leq V$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ we have $$\int_a^bUdx \leq \int_a^b f(x)dx \leq \int_a^bVdx$$ which gives $$U(b-a) \leq \int_a^b f(x)dx \leq V(b-a).$$ Dividing by $(b - a)$ we have $$U \leq \frac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b f(x)dx \leq V.$$ Now apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to obtain the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was exactly what I needed.